# Core Plot vs Core Graphics

Tags: graph, core-graphics, core-plot

I am new in ios development.
I have to draw few graphs (Bar chart, Pie chart, Scatter chart), should i use core plot or can i do this using core graphics. which one will be better in performance, memory and speed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core Plot probably uses Core Graphics. Essentially, it does what you'd be doing without it.

The general rule is to do whatever's easiest first, then see what performance problems you have, and *then* optimize. As the proverb goes, “premature optimization is the root of all evil”—meaning that trying to guess what will be slow (or memory-hungry, or whatever) will cause more problems than you solve.

So, use Core Plot. If you find that it causes a performance problem, see if you can solve it in Core Plot; if so, you should contribute your fix back to the Core Plot project so that all users of that library get the same benefit (as you presumably would have them do if they were in your situation).

If, and only if, you find that Core Plot does not do what you need it to do and cannot feasibly be extended to do it, or that it ruins your performance and somehow cannot be fixed, then, and only then, you should write your own plotting code, taking care to avoid causing the same problem.